# Variable within Excel formula

Tags: excel, variables, if-statement

I have a cell stating the year. I am making a reference from another cell to a column named `"Rent 2017"`. I want the employees to change the cell containing the year every January 1st.

So,

Cell containing the year: `'Sheet 2'!B4`

Cell code for the one referencing to `"Rent 2017": IF([@[Rent 2017]]; 1+1; 0)`

How can I make it dynamic?

This is what I tried:

```
IF([@[Rent 'Sheet2'!B4]]; 1+1; 0)
```

Hope I have been at least sort of clear about what it is that I want to achieve.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic?  what does the input look like and what do you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 0):

Use `INDIRECT` to concatenate the string and cell value:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("[@[Rent "&'Sheet2'!B4&"]]"); 1+1; 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understood exactly what you are trying to achieve, but YEAR(NOW()) gives 2017 directly which you could concatenate with RENT like so : ="RENT"&year(now()) ...